# How to specify source directory for pip VCS package installed through an anaconda environment.yml

Tags: pip, anaconda, environment

I have the following directory structure:

```
Application
|
--- Project 1
|
--- Project 2       
| 
--- Application_install_requirements 
                |
                -- environment.yml
                | 
                -- otherdependency
                         |
                         --otherdependency.whl
```

The environment.yml looks like:

```
name: Application_env
channels:
        - defaults
        - conda-forge
dependencies:
        - python=3.6.5
....
        - pip:
          - recordclass
          - keyboard
          - otherdependency/otherdependency.whl
....

          - -e git+git@bitbucket.org://git.repo/some_pkg.git#egg=Project1
```

I want to be able to pip install an editable of Project 1 that I can do version control through Application/Project 1/src. If possible, I would like it so this can be done through the conda environment.yml specifications and conda env update.

When I run conda env update -f "Application/Application_install_requirements/environment.yml" I get the desired src directory under Application_install_requirements, not Project 1. This makes the system work, but I have to go to Application/Application_install_requirements/src/Project 1/src to edit, 
not the desired Application/Project 1/src.

Result:

```
Application
|
--- Project 1
|
--- Project 2       
| 
--- Application_install_requirements 
                |
                -- environment.yml
                |
                **-- src**
                | 
                -- otherdependency
                         |
                         --otherdependency.whl
```

Desired:

```
Application
|
--- Project 1
|      |
|      **-- src**
|
--- Project 2       
| 
--- Application_install_requirements 
                |
                -- environment.yml
                | 
                -- otherdependency
                         |
                         --otherdependency.whl
```

I do not want Application_install_requirements to be inside Project 1 because it contains dependencies for Project 2 as well.

Per the documentation on pip's https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support:

```
"For editable installs, the clone location by default is <venv path>/src/SomeProject in virtual environments, and <cwd>/src/SomeProject for global installs. The --src option can be used to modify this location."
```

Here's what I've tried:

### 1.

conda activate Application_env,

cd into the Application/Project 1 directory,

run conda env update -f ".../path/to/environment.yml"

I hoped this would trigger the < cwd >/src/SomeProject default, but it didn't. It also didn't install src in < venvpath >/src/SomeProject; it installed it in Application_install_requirements, where the environment.yml file is.

### 2.

Add a --src option to the environment.yml to specify where to install the src editable files.

New environment.yml:

```
name: Application_env
channels:
        - defaults
        - conda-forge
dependencies:
        - python=3.6.5
....
        - pip:
          - recordclass
          - keyboard
          - otherdependency/otherdependency.whl
....

          - -e git+git@bitbucket.org://git.repo/some_pkg.git#egg=Project1  --src=<pathtoapplication>/Project 1
```

and then run conda env update -f  "/Application_install_requirements/environment.yml"

Conda failed to install src in any directory through pip as seen by the terminal output:

```
###
Pip subprocess output:

#
# To activate this environment, use
#
#     $ conda activate Application_env
#
# To deactivate an active environment, use
#
#     $ conda deactivate
###
```

### 3.

Manually move the src folder from Application_install_requirements to Project 1 and edit the file < venv_path >/Lib/site-packages/Project 1.egg-link, which is just a file with the name of the address where src is installed from:

```
<path to>/Application/Application/install_requirements/src
```

to

```
<path to>/Application/Project 1/src
```

This didn't work, as the installed package still looked for the src in the originally installed folder.